# Do I have to rely on compiler NRVO?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

I need to call a function which returns back an object for me. The problem is that the object has a destructor which can ruin the data before the function output is being assigned into another object.
In my program, I have an operator+ which adds two matrices and returns the sum of both matrices:

```
C=A+B
```

According to **The Name Return Value Optimization (NRVO)**, the following code should not call the destructor right away:

```
Matrix operator+(const Matrix &m1, const Matrix &m2)
{
    Matrix sum;
    m1.clone(sum);
    for...
        for...
            sum.members[i][j]+=m2.members[i][j];
    return sum;
}
```

My problem is that I am not confident with trusting on NRVO as it depends the compiler. If I give the code to someone else, he might compile the code and his compiler gives a different result.

So, is there any way to force the compiler to give me what exactly I need or I must change my code to an undesirable form as following?

```
Matrix sum(Matrix &result, const Matrix &m1, const Matrix &m2)
```

**edit:**

Just to explain more, I assume by considering NRVO, the probram runs as following:

```
compiler reaches to C=A+B
operator + is called
object sum is created
object sum is calculated as sum of m1 and m2
sum is returned but its destructor is not called
the value of sum is directed to variable C
after function containing variable C reaches end, the destructor of C is called.
```

While when NRVO is not applied, I expect:

```
compiler reaches to C=A+B
operator + is called
object sum is created
object sum is calculated as sum of m1 and m2
sum is returned and its destructor is called which releases all data allocations
the return value of the operator+ is already destroyed so an invalid data is associated to variable C
...
```

Comment: If your class does what you say it does, you need to fix it.

Comment: Code that you write should not depend on a specific compiler optimization to function properly.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read up about object lifetimes. Please point out the locations in your code where you expect destructor invocations and we should be able to get this cleared up.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is exactly my problem. Anyway to fix it without loosing the advantage of OO operators?

Comment: What object or objects do you think might get collected prematurely?

Comment: `C` gets copy constructed from the returned `sum` and only after that the destructor of `sum` is called. I think you're misunderstanding this, or you're doing something really evil in your code. It would be nice to see the destructor and the copy constructor so we can tell if there's something wrong.

Comment: @barej - As long as your copy constructor and assignment operators have no side-effects, then there is nothing to worry about.  The compiler can be terrible and not have NRVO, or it could be the latest whiz-bang release from clang, gcc, of MS, and the code will give the same results.

Comment: @RobertHarvey please consider the part that I added after editing the post.

Comment: @baref - Stop worrying, seriously.  Again, if your copy constructor and assignment operator are not coded in a weird way that would produce side-effects, relax.

Comment: @barej the destructor is always called **AFTER** the copy constructor finished, otherwise return by value would be broken and could never be used in c++, no1 would use c++ if it would behave that way. The only thing NRVO does is avoid having to call the copy constructor at all by constructing it at right place to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the object has a destructor which can ruin the data before the function output is being assigned into another object.

This is not a problem. Object either will be copied properly or unnecessary copy will be eliminated by optimization. If your copy ctor implemented properly the end result would be the same (except less optimal code of course). If object copy is prohibitively expensive you probably should  use copy on write semantics and actual Matrix object would be a thin wrapper to real object created on the heap.

What will actually happen when NRVO is not applied:

```
compiler reaches to C=A+B
operator + is called
object sum is created
object sum is calculated as sum of m1 and m2
temporary object of type Matrix created as a copy of object sum
object sum destroyed
temporary assigned to C
```

as you can see end result is the same, just less effective (temporary object created)